# как передать static файл через koa-router

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-router, koa.js

Мне нужно, чтобы переходя на любой роут моего приложения koa всегда передавал файл index.html, т.к. роутинг идёт через react-router.

Если я делаю что-то вида

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const serve = require('koa-static');
const app = new Koa();
app.use(serve('./build'));
```

Это работает и можно переходить по ссылкам, но если я ввиду url отличный от localhost:3000/, то мне тут появиться ошибка Not found

на Express то, что мне нужно выглядит так:

```
app.get('/*', (req,res) => {
  res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
})
```

Вот так не работает:

```
const Router = require('koa-router');
const router = new Router();
router.get("/*", function (ctx) {
    serve('./build');
})
```

Получалось реализовать через koa-mount, но там нельзя указать регулярное выражение в роуте.

Благодарю за отклик!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То что мне нужно было реализуется примерно таким образом:

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

const serve = require('koa-static');
app.use(serve("build")

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const Router = require('koa-router');
const router = new Router();

router.get('*', function(ctx) {
    ctx.body = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(path.join('build', 'index.html')), 'utf8')
});

app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());

app.listen(3000);
```